# Using selenium Webdriver how to check if the webelement is outside the visible area of the screen?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to check that before scrolling the webpage the element is not visible. The element is actually present on webpage but not visible on the screen. Once I scroll the webpage, the element becomes visible to user.

How can I automate above scenario?

Answer (score 3):

I Found a way to check if the element was visible.

The idea is to get the 1. scroll position of the page; 2. the height of the browser's visible area, and 3. the element's y-location.

```
    scroll_position_script = """
        var pageY;
        if (typeof(window.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
            pageY = window.pageYOffset;
        } else {
            pageY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        return pageY;
    """

    yOffset = self.browser.execute_script(scroll_position_script)

    js_client_height = "return document.documentElement.clientHeight;"
    browser_height = self.browser.execute_script(js_client_height)

    elem_yloc = int(element.location['y'])
    self.assertTrue(elem_yloc>=yOffset and elem_yloc<=yOffset+browser_height)
```

Comment: This was a python-specific code.
  self.browser refers to the webdriver instance. There would be an equivalent call for execute_script in Java etc. The last line makes sure that the element's y location is between the screen top (yOffset) and the bottom (yOffset+browser_height)

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to automate these type of tests with any test automation tool, because this test wont be reliable and will not pass consistently for the following main reasons.

1. How would you ensure that the specific element is not visible across different browsers?
2. What about running the same test on different screen resolutions?
3. Similarly running the same test on different size of monitors?

Answer (score 0):

What @haroonzone said. It can't be done reliably.

That said, I'd give it some try with [`getLocation()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getLocation%28%29) and [`getSize()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getSize%28%29) methods on WebElement.

In conjencture with `driver.manage().window().`[`getSize()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#getSize%28%29).

Or maybe some play with JavaScript [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window). Namely [`innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerHeight) and [`innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerWidth) on `window`, `document`, or maybe `document.body` DOM elements. If you don't want scrollbars to be counted into the viewport, use [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth) and [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight).

[This link](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/html/288284/288284/how-to-get-inner-window-widthheight-not-screen/) gives some advanced advice for IE, since IE obviously works differently.

Try it and see how it went.