# Detect user visible elements(only in viewport) by xpath in selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to only click on elements that would actually be visible to a user, i.e. don't click on elements outside the where I am currently scrolled to on a website.

I manage to detect all the ones that are hidden, but how to get a list of only elements a normal user would be able to see.

Comment: share your code and HTML and error trace if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I right understand you, you are locating a bunch of elements like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")
```

it will give you a list of elements. Some of this elements are visible, some of them not. To prove it you can use this:

```
for element in elements:
    print(element.is_displayed()) # prints true if displayed, otherwise false
```

Try this code snippet:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
driver.get(url)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a") # finds all elements by given xPath
for element in elements: # for every element in elements list
    print(element.is_displayed()) # print 'true' if displayed, or 'false' if not

print("DONE")
```

Output:

```
False
True
False
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
...
DONE
```

**NOTE:** it is only an example, normally you have to wait until the page fully loads to locate all elements correctly and also get the correct state of them.

EDIT: I have found a nice solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771094/how-can-i-check-if-an-element-is-completely-visible-on-the-screen) and the sample code in this case would be like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span")

def element_in_viewport(driver, elem):
    elem_left_bound = elem.location.get('x')
    elem_top_bound = elem.location.get('y')
    elem_width = elem.size.get('width')
    elem_height = elem.size.get('height')
    elem_right_bound = elem_left_bound + elem_width
    elem_lower_bound = elem_top_bound + elem_height

    win_upper_bound = driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset')
    win_left_bound = driver.execute_script('return window.pageXOffset')
    win_width = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.clientWidth')
    win_height = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.clientHeight')
    win_right_bound = win_left_bound + win_width
    win_lower_bound = win_upper_bound + win_height

    return all((win_left_bound <= elem_left_bound,
                win_right_bound >= elem_right_bound,
                win_upper_bound <= elem_top_bound,
                win_lower_bound >= elem_lower_bound)
               )

for element in elements:
    print(element_in_viewport(driver, element))

print("DONE")
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
...
DONE
```

In my perspective this code snippet works good.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above, the problem is that it still shows elements which a user would not be able to see, as it is outside the display area on the screen, i.e. I would have to scroll down further to see this.

Comment: Ah I see what you need. But why do you need this? the user is also able to scroll the page.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that if I want to scrap a page looking like a user, then I can't press elements which the user shouldnt be able to see. Which the website can detect as it can detect how far down I scrolled using javascript

Comment: @J.Doe I think I have found a solution for your problem, please check the updated answer.